# How to use C macro for both numbers and strings?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
    if (termAttributes.c_lflag & OPOST)
      puts("c_lflag = OPOST");
    if (termAttributes.c_lflag & OLCUC)
      puts("c_lflag = OLCUC");
```

I have some code like the above. I want to simplify it as something like this.

```
TCFLAGPRINT(termAttributes, c_lflag, OPOST)
TCFLAGPRINT(termAttributes, c_lflag, OLCUC)
```

Could anybody show how to define TCFLAGPRINT?

Comment: What specifically is the issue?  Putting the macro name into string form, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#define TCFLAGPRINT(tio, field, flag) \
    do { \
        if ((tio).field & (flag))   \
            puts(#field " = " #flag); \
    } while (0)
```

The `do {` `} while (0)` wrapper is a common idiom that forces you to add a semicolon to the end of the macro call. (In this case, it also prevents you adding `else` after the macro call.)

The `#` operator before a macro parameter name in the replacement text of the function-like macro converts the parameter name to a string literal.

The `#field " = " #flag` is concatenating three string literals into a single string constant.

Answer (score 0):

I print bit masks quite a lot so I've come up with my own mechanism for this.

I use a `struct` table and some functions.

I've pulled in some of my code from a library to illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned long tgb_val;
    const char *tgb_tag;
    const char *tgb_reason;
} tgb_t;

#define TGBEOT \
    { .tgb_tag = NULL }

#define TGBMORE(_tgb) \
    _tgb->tgb_tag != NULL

#define _TGBFORALL(_tgb) \
    ;  TGBMORE(_tgb);  ++_tgb
#define TGBFORALL(_tga,_tgb) \
    _tgb = _tga;  TGBMORE(_tgb);  ++_tgb

#define TGBDUAL(_sym) \
    { .tgb_val = _sym, .tgb_tag = #_sym },

tgb_t lflag_tgb[] = {
    TGBDUAL(OPOST)
    TGBDUAL(OLCUC)
    TGBEOT
};

// tgbmskdcd -- decode mask value
char *
tgbmskdcd(char *buf,const tgb_t *tgb,unsigned long val)
{
    const char *tag;
    int sep;
    char *bp;
    int len;

    bp = buf;
    *bp = 0;
    sep = 0;

    for (TGBFORALL(tgb,tgb)) {
        if ((val & tgb->tgb_val) == 0)
            continue;

        if (sep)
            *bp++ = ' ';
        sep = 1;

        tag = tgb->tgb_tag;
        len = strlen(tag);
        strcpy(bp,tag);
        bp += len;
    }

    return buf;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct termios term;
    char buf[100];

    tcgetattr(1,&term);
    printf("c_lflag: %s\n",tgbmskdcd(buf,lflag_tgb,term.c_lflag));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output:

```
c_lflag: OPOST OLCUC
```